# How can I recode every i to i-1

Tags: r, recode

I have data like

```
table(data$num)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ....         100
# 10 2  13 2  7  8  19              2
```

I want to recode every i to i-1, like

```
table(data$num)
# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ....         99
# 10 2  13 2  7  8  19              2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: those are names,do `table(dat$num - 1)`

Comment: While @RonahShah's answer gets you what you asked for, I find it odd that you are manually changing the labels of a table. If `data$num` should be 0-based in the data, why don't you fix it there before making a table of it? (`dat$num <- dat$num - 1L`)

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
table(data$num - 1)
```

Taking `mtcars` as example :

```
table(mtcars$cyl)

# 4  6  8 
#11  7 14 
table(mtcars$cyl - 1)

# 3  5  7 
#11  7 14
```